# Multiprocessing without copying data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.9

I have a **VERY** large data structure, on which I need to run multiple functions, none of which are mutating (therefore, no risk of a race condition. I simply want to get the results faster by running these functions in parallel. For example, getting percentile values for a large data set)

How would I achieve this with multiprocessing, **without having to create a copy of the data** each time a process starts, which would end up making things slower than if I hadn’t bothered in the first place ?

---

(*The absence of a code example is on purpose, as I don’t think the details of the data structure and functions are in any way relevant.*)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks ! I should be able to refactor to use this. I am however a bit concerned that none of the examples on the page actually start any processes, but I should be able to find one

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes